# How to change specific dates in POSIXct/POSIXt format to NA

Tags: r, datetime, posix, datetime-format, posixct

I have imported an SPSS file, which contains several date/time variables of the following class:

```
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

The user-defined missing value for these variables is `8888-08-08 00:00:00`. How can I convert this value to `NA` for the set of relevant date/time variables in R?

I tried running `df$datetime[df$datetime == "8888-08-08"] <- NA` as well as `df$datetime[df$datetime == as.Date("8888-08-08")] <- NA` to no avail.

Comment: This should work `df$datetime[as.character(df$datetime) == "8888-08-08"] <- NA`

Comment: Thanks, @AndreWildberg - that did the trick! If I wanted to extend this to multiple columns (rather than recoding each column to NA individually), how can I adjust the `df$datetime` portion to accomplish that?

Comment: Probably with `sapply` or using `dplyr`, e.g. `sapply(df[,2:3], function(x) ifelse(as.character(x) == "8888-08-08", NA, x))`

Answer (score 0):

As these are in `POSIXct`, use the same type to convert and assign to `NA`

```
df$datetime[df$datetime == as.POSIXct("8888-08-08 00:00:00")] <- NA
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(datetime = sample(c(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 1:5, 
     as.POSIXct("8888-08-08 00:00:00")), 20, replace =TRUE))
```

Comment: One could also use `df$datetime[df$datetime >= as.POSIXct("8888-08-08 00:00:00")] <- NA` but in 1134 years, this script would return undesired results.